# Check / Uncheck Input Boxes with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking through posts trying to find the answer, but haven't had any luck, so hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

When I use the following code, it checks all the input boxes and it unchecks them. However, if I click the check all again, it doesn't check them all. Why is that?

**JQuery**

```
  $('document').ready( function() {
    $('.check_boxes').click( function() {
      if ( $(':checkbox').attr('checked')) {
        $(':checkbox').attr('checked', false);
      } else {
        $(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);
      }     
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check_boxes" id="check_all" />
```

Comment: try using `.prop` instead of `.attr`

Comment: Ok here is your demo http://jsfiddle.net/vhLMN/14/ what do you want here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**js**

```
  $('document').ready( function() {
    $('.check_boxes').click( function() {
      if ( $('input:checkbox').prop('checked')) {
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
      } else {
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      }     
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZcr8/6/)

Comment: Thank you. If one of the inputs is checked the check all input still stays checked :/

Comment: I thought you want a checkbox to check/uncheck all. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes that's true...just thought it would uncheck if one of the inputs were unchecked. I'm still learning js.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need this simple code:

```
$('document').ready( function() {
$('.check_boxes').click( function() {
  if ( $(':checkbox').prop('checked')) {
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  }     
 });
});
```

Comment: Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/vhLMN/17/

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I wasn't too far off :) I tried using .prop() before and it didn't work the way I had the code. Now, how would I automatically uncheck the check all input if one of the inputs is unchecked?

Comment: Line 3 needs to be .prop too, correct? Otherwise my code doesn't work.

Comment: That does not work. See http://jsfiddle.net/vhLMN/21/

Comment: Neither of those work, see http://jsfiddle.net/vhLMN/23/

Answer (score 0):

Actually once you click on the checkbox, the first if is always true. Hence all checkeboxes get unchecked (including the one you clicked).

I assume you wanted this behavior:
http://jsfiddle.net/vhLMN/18/

```
$('document').ready( function() {
    $('.check_boxes').click( function() {
      if ( !this.checked ) {
        $('.flip_us :checkbox').attr('checked', false);
      } else {
        $('.flip_us :checkbox').attr('checked', true);
      };     
    });
});
```

BTW. There is no `label` **attribute** on inputs. You should fix this unless you are using some framework that uses it to create actual `label` **tag**.

Comment: nice catch, that should be `id=` thanks!